# Access email account info

Tags: android

Is there any way that i can access the email accounts that are saved
in the default email client of android.

Basically I want to access the inbox and display their mails without
asking for username and password.

Does AccountManager class thats available in android version 2 answer
my query? and if yes then is there any alternative for v1.5 or v1.6.

Comment: This does not belong on SuperUser.

Comment: AccountManager does answer your query, and no, there is no alternative. There's no way of finding out the account name of the account associated with the telephone, prior to android 2

Comment: Whoops, my bad... my eyes (read: brain) have been failing me of late :D

Comment: @AliDeo: Are you interested in programming this solution?

Comment: @David Hedlund, how can I get main gmail address in API level 5 and higher using `AccountManager`? It looks like it provides `Account` objects and these contain nothing more than name and type.

Comment: @radek: does this answer you question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Answer (score -2):

Try going to Settings, then Accounts & sync.  Your Gmail and other accounts should be listed under Manage accounts.

Comment: He's trying to access account info via the SDK, not as a 'user of the phone'