# How to save data for app to device calendar

Tags: android

I have created an application which contains certain date option.

Now suppose on some date I have write notes my app.

Now when I press my submit button, these notes are save in the device calendar.

So, is it possible to save the data that you used in your application directly in the device calendar based on the date you have selected for saving data? Moreover, when I delete my data from the app, the data saved in the device calendar is also deleted.

Comment: ok paresh..i will concentarte on that

Comment: hi prakash is can you please give me the answer for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html

There is a Java library for API version 2.0. Try using that to modify a particular user's Google Calendar.

You can find the current user's e-mail ID (Google account) from this question: [How can you get an Android user's email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556495/get-owners-email-address)

Update:

Here is a sequence that might work:

- Authentication - The first step would be to have the user login into his Google account. Link: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html
- List calendars - Next, ask the user to select which calendar he wants to use. Check here to see how to get list of calendars: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#RetrievingCalendars
- Add Event - Finally, add the event to the selected calendar: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingSingle

Obviously there might be steps I have missed. Do try these out and read the documentation to see if some steps are required in between

Comment: its quiet complicated here..all things are bounce from my head..can u please explain me with simple examples

Comment: hi sparky..so do you find any simple example for that.

Comment: No. I didn't. The only way may be to go through the documentation. I will update the answers with some steps you can follow.

Comment: hey spark i read all the documents..but its quiet complicated..actually is there are no application done that add events in the device calender..i means to say that i dont need such complicated work what i need is simply add event from my app to device calender

Comment: Perhaps there is no simple way. I couldn't find one anyway.

Comment: i am sending you a link where they give a code for adding event in the device calender..u check i try to implement it but not sucess..i think you can do it..http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/08/09/add-events-on-google-calendar-on-android-froyo/

Comment: will try it at home later, and let you know

Comment: sorry.. not yet.. got caught up with work.. in fact, still busy.. will get back to you

Comment: @sparkymat let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/950/discussion-between-anshuman-and-sparkymat)

Answer (score 0):

To modify a user's Google Calendar, use the Google Calendar GData API.

Comment: Can you please explain me with an example..if you dont mine