# How to get Current Active Google play account in Android

Tags: android, google-play

I can able to get all the configured gmails using below code snippet

```
 Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();

for (Account account : accounts) {

 Log.e("Gmail","gmail "+account.name);

}
```

With the above snippet, I am getting more than one Gmail. But I need only current active gmail. Guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

**[There is no concept of primary email id or current active google account in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450994/get-primary-email-account-of-android-phone).**

You can get the google accounts of user which has been logged in on that phone.

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
if(accounts != null && accounts.length > 0) {
    ArrayList playAccounts = new ArrayList();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        String name = account.name;
        String type = account.type;
        if(account.type.equals("com.google")) {
            playAccounts.add(ac.name);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Account Info: " + name + ":" + type);
    }
    Log.d("tag", "Google Play Accounts present on phone are :: " + playAccounts);
}
```

As per the answer suggested in above link is to select the last account which you got in list, to get the first account added in android.

```
String emailId = playAccounts.get(playAccounts.size()-1);
```

**Update - 1**

You'll need `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission to access accounts.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>`

Hope it'll help.

Comment: I changed the solution and added explanation about primary email id.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a less verbose approach (Kotlin)

```
val playAccounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google")
```