# How to distinct android main contact in android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have several raw contacts linked to one contact:

```
_id - 130
contact_id - 17434
account_type - com.google
aggregation_mode - 0
account_name - ...@gmail.com
display_name - ...
raw_contact_is_user_profile - 0

_id - 230
contact_id - 17434
account_type - com.whatsapp
aggregation_mode - 0
account_name - WhatsApp
display_name - ...
raw_contact_is_user_profile - 0


_id - 17217
contact_id - 17434
account_type - com.example
aggregation_mode - 0
account_name - Example
display_name - ...
raw_contact_is_user_profile - 0
```

They belong to different accounts, is there a solid way to get which one is the "main" raw contact? One possible solution is to check how many fields in `DATA` column each contact has, but looks more like a hack.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can check the id of these raw contact with the "main" contact id. Then you may know it.

Comment: @UmangBurman but how do i get which one is the main?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you already have the main id and you need to check from the list of ids.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no concept of a primary account, so as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913527/how-to-get-current-active-google-play-account-in-android) I can use either `com.google` or the ones without account for the case when the user doesn't sync their contacts.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found out, there's no such concept of a main contact in RawContacts, however, you can't really rely of each contact either having a Google raw, or a phone-only raw.

You'll find there are users that have contacts comprised of exchange contacts, or Yahoo contacts, or others you haven't heard of, or contacts with any combination of those and others.

Whatever it is you're trying to do, there should be a way to do it without selecting a single raw out of the joined raws