# how to know email id of whom downloaded the app from Google Play

Tags: android, email, google-play

I downloaded an app on Google Play, opened it without any login, and after one day, I received a welcome email from the app team in my inbox. This raised one question in my mind: Is it possible to get the email id of the one who downloaded the app on Google Play?

What I knew: I can only get email id of user from database, when user completes login with detail.

Anyone have any idea how to know email id of whom downloaded the app without login step, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the primary email saved in the device. With a bit of research you would've get to this answer: [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Comment: Thanks Andrew very much. This is what I am looking for. Based on your hint, I found the quite completed code. Post here for ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556495/how-can-you-get-an-android-users-email-address/2556540#2556540