# get email account name programmatically android

Tags: android, email, shared

I wish to find out how to get following details in android:

· 
          Account name

·         POP3 address

·         SMTP address

·         Username

·         OWA address if connecting through Exchange

·         Internet profile through which it is connected.

Comment: This is only a partial answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address