# How to get the First Gmail account detail when we switch ON our phone and register it

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have the following code that is getting all the gmail id's that are synchronized with my phone but i want the Main gmail id that user register the first time. Because all the other gmail accounts(not main) if i want i can delete anytime but to delete the main account we have to done other things too, So that's why i want to get the main account to use into my application.

here's my code i think to add some filter in it, i can do that but can't able to get the thing correctly.

```
Account[] accounts=AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
    for(Account account: accounts)
    {
        String possibleEmail=account.name;
        Log.d("Possible email id's of user", possibleEmail);
    }
```

i already seen [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) link but didn't able to convert it in right manner. 
I want to use this main email id for push notification using C2DM from google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an answer, but it was not a correct way to do it. As i am getting all the accounts associated with google(gmail) and as we enter the email id's to be synchronized with gmail a stack is created and on 0th position, I am getting the primary Gmail id that was first enter by the user when he switched ON his phone.

```
    Account[] accounts=AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
    String myEmailid=accounts[0].toString();
    Log.d("My email id that i want", myEmailid);
    for(Account account: accounts)
    {
        String possibleEmail=account.toString();
        Log.d("Possible email id of user", possibleEmail);

    }
```

If someone has a better solution then let me know, i tested this example on 2 phones and it works fine, but i see many applications that are fetching the primary email id of users to send email and all, i want to know how they are doing?

Answer (score 1):

If you find more than one account of the type you're looking for you should probably let the user choose. Android 3 has no "primary account" distinction; you can remove any account from the device regardless of whether it was the first account added or not.

Comment: Yah got your point adamp but the thing is i want to use this gmail account to send the push notification if user delete the account that is not primary but he choose it to send the notification then my notification wont work at all, So thats why i want to get the Main gmail id for push notification.

Comment: yah i am able to get the account types for twitter for facebook for google but the problem is whenever i am filtering it with com.google i got two, three as much the accounts that are synchronized but didn't able to differentiate between them as primary.

Answer (score 0):

Following code gets the email addresses and dosn't require any GET_ACCOUNTS permission....

```
  private static final int REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL = 1;
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        ...
        try {
            Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                    new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, false, null, null, null, null);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO
        }
        ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            email.setText(accountName);
        }
    }
```