# Add the Sender's email id to CC through Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created and Simple app to send e-mail using **Intent**, with dynamic fields(get required fields at runtime). It works fine.

But i need to add **CC** to the sender email id. The email has to be sent for the sender email id when it is also sent to the recipient mail-id.

I know the procedure to add the **CC** through intent by this code.

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "sender's mail id");
```

I need the sender's email id to put there. I've tried this for lot of time. But, not yet result get it. Anyone guide me. Thanks in Advance.

**Update -**

From this [Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) I can successfully add the Gmail's Primary email id. But, if i choose the Email instead of Gmail, i can't get primary email id. I've use this code to fetch the email id -

```
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(TestActivity.this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccounts();
    int size = accounts.length;
    String[] names = new String[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        names[i] = accounts[i].name;
    }
```

If i use this code means, i can get the all Synchronized email accounts which are all synchronized in Gmail but not in Email. Why this happend? Anyone Guide me?

Comment: how are you getting the mail in your app? Through broadcastListeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to get user's EmailID

You can get user's ID and as well Device's Primary ID

Use this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) to get that.

And add them to your Intent.

> I understand what you want,but I doubt It's not possible cause Once you
>   fired any intent,then User will select Email or Gmail , But you have
>   set CC long before so you can't update it's value depend on user
>   selection simple.