# How to get non-primary purchase account email address

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Prior to the introduction of Android 3.0, the first `com.google` account registered on a phone was the primary account, and the only account used by Android Market.

On devices on Android 3.0 and up I can no longer rely on this (`Account[0]`) to get the customer's email address.

Is there a way to tell **which** account `com.google` account is currently making the purchase?

(all I need is the *index* into the `Account[]` array for account type `com.google`. I can get the email address once I have the relevant index)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it's not possible. From what I've found it looks like that the account making the in-app-purchase is the account used to install the app, which you don't know. I guess it might be possible to read it from the Play store application database on rooted phones.

It looks like that it's not even possible to find the purchasing account after the purchase has been done using the [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/purchases/get), not sure why is that though.

If you, by any chance, find that out, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick google search and came across this on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address).

You can use `AccountManager.getAccounts` or `AccountManager.getAccountsByType` to get a list of all account names on the device. Fortunately, for certain account types (including `com.google`), the account names are email addresses. Example snippet below.

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+ Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts(); for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        ...
    } }
```

Note that this requires the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

More on using `AccountManager` can be found at the [Contact Manager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/src/com/example/android/contactmanager/ContactAdder.html) sample code in the SDK.

Answer (score -1):

firs name and last name  >>  java code ?

email add code

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (account.type.equals("com.google")) {
        email = account.name.toString();
        break;
    } else if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        email = account.name.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to give more explanation.

Comment: used to get the mail address on the android device

Answer (score -2):

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");        

//you can set current sync account..

boolean syncEnabled = ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(accounts[0], ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);
```