# Getting Android Play/Market ID of the user

Tags: android

Is it possible to somehow get the ID of the user with which they are currently logged in on Andoid Play?

It would be really useful for the developers. They won't need to have users signed up on each application. They could just identify the user by their Android Play ID.

Comment: do you mean the name of their google account?

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/2112965/1300995.

Comment: @Tim yes I mean google account

Comment: @biegleux .. I'll try the solution suggested on that post. If it works I'll either mark my post a duplicate or will delete it. Thank a lot because it seems to be a useful link so far.

Comment: you should wait for it to get closed as a dupelicate IMO, the system frowns upon slightly deleting to many of your own questions. Also as a closed question it will still remain online with a link to the proper answer which might make it easier in the figure to find the answer they need.