# Intent that goes to installed apps list on Google Play

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I'm looking for a way to go for my installed apps list on google play.

I know how to go directly to my apps, but I'm looking for action that would redirect me to the list of installed applications on Google Play

: (google play/my apps)

is there any action defined that could do the work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of Installed App From Google Play Against Google Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718822/list-of-installed-app-from-google-play-against-google-account)

Answer (score 0):

There are no intent or google API. But you can parse it.