# Getting user's real name from google account

Tags: android, google-account

Is there a way to get user's real name as set in Google account?

I can use **AccountManager.get(ctx).getAccountsByType("com.google")** to get user's google email address. 
However I'd like to get real name, for greeting user nicely in my app.

Is there some Android API to get this info?

Comment: Do you use the account for anything else? If not you would request the USE_CREDENTIALS permission just for this. This permission is very powerful and should only be requested by an app if there is a serious reason.

Comment: Yes I do need USE_CREDENTIALS for other features.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this only in Android 4.0 (API level 14 +)

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) post.

Comment: That returns email, not the name.