# How to get Get 'me' contact from contactlist of Android

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

On my Android phone I have a special contact set in my Contact List called "Personal Profile" that obviously does not appear in the contact list because contain my personal informations.
I know that in other phones this contact is called in a different way... but is there...

I want to access this contact from my app so I have one more chance to get the user phone number. (I know, there is a calssic method that query the SIM, but in italy 80% of sims have that field empty)

Do you know how could I get that contact info?

Comment: I'm confused "I have a special contact set in my Contact List called "Personal Profile" that obviously does not appear in the contact list". Does it appear in the contact list or not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: @Samuel it's strange but it is so. The "personale profile" contact is in the contact list but it is accessible only via Menu. Menu->'Personal Profile' display a contact screen with my address,phone etc. details.

Comment: @AmanGautam Thanks for the link... but i haven't got how to retrive the phone number instead of the email.