# Fatal Exception: Main

Tags: android, exception, android-logcat

I'm new to android and having a problem with my first application that I have extended by using the Hello World. Logcat is appended. Can anyone please help why the application shuts down ?

```
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.livelihood.hello.world.ScanSMSReceiver: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2126)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.livelihood.hello.world.ScanSMSReceiver.onReceive(ScanSMSReceiver.java:40)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2119)
09-27 19:05:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: in that case, you are trying to get data from array which length is 0

Comment: and add some code here it will be use full to find error..

Comment: can you post your hello world program code line no  40 from ScanSMSReceiver.java

Comment: @PadmaKumar this is my line number 39 and 40 from the ScanSMSReceiver.java please      Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google");
    final String primaryEmail = accounts[0].name;

Comment: @SamirMangroliya ....could you please explain a bit more since I'm totally unaware what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

In line #40 in your ScanSMSReceiver.java class you're using an Array object that you did not instantiate properly.

Then error is telling you that you're trying to asccess index 0 from an array that has 0 objects in it. If you try and access an index which is more than 1 less of the number of items (number of items in an array -1) then your program will throw a

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

and crash your program.

Go through your code and check to see where you declared your Array object and instantiate it with a specific size

```
int[] myArray = new int[5];
```

(Or whichever type of array you're using)
Then when you try and access index 0 it will no longer crash.

Comment: though it all sounded greek to me but I'm really glad for your help sir :)...I'll do as you have guided and get back to you if you can still help. Can you please look through the line 39 and 40 of my ScanSMSReceived.java class which I attach here                                                   Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google");
    final String primaryEmail = accounts[0].name;

Comment: It looks like AcountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google"); is returning an empty array so when you try and do accounts[0].name; it crashes because there is no item in it. I would need you to post the method or class that you are calling this from to help ya out more. Edit your question above and copy and paste you code

Comment: public class ScanSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                                                                            Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)                 { Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType("com.google");
 final String primaryEmail = accounts[0].name;

Comment: please help sorry for the delayed respone

Comment: Check out the answer on this. Its exactly what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address