# Reading the "me" contact card

Tags: android, android-contacts

Starting with some API, Google decided to add a "me" contact, describing info of the device's owner.

How do you read the info of this contact? Is it even possible? And from which API can I assume it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question's on here, but phrased differently.  Just wanted to redirect others who came to this question:

Actual question:

[How to get the user profile on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350844/how-to-get-the-user-profile-on-android-device)

Which redirects you to a slightly different version, but which has what you're probably looking for:

[How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address/2175688#2175688)

Comment: seems legit, so you say all i need to do is add whichever fields i want for the "PROJECTION" variable?