# Android Market get buyer mail automatically for authentification

Tags: android, google-play

I'm currently making a multiplatform game that targets android. I would like to be able to get notification when someone buy my app to add him to the "activable mail" in my database to let him create an account in the same database. So what I need is google to send me the mail of the buyers automatically by whatever way. I've read a bit about the Notification API but it doesn't seem to work with the Android market.

Answer (score 1):

AccountManager should help:
[How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Some extra permissions needed and there can be more than one android account, so you should ask user to choose one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google checkout API to get notified for purchases. IIRC, it includes some info about the user, including email address. It is only available in the US (and maybe UK), so if you are in a another country you are out of luck. Look for a 'merchant key' in the Checkout console, if you can find one, you can use the API.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There exists no API to do what you want.

Your best bet is just adding whatever notification you need to send to the first run of your application. That way after someone buys it and runs it the first time it will send a notification to your server or wherever you need it to go.