# How to find account information relevant to in app billing transaction

Tags: android-billing

Google documentation specifies that an in application billing transaction is linked to the account that is set as primary on a device. How can we find with which account the transaction was made if the user has more than one google account registered in his phone.
I have also researched this link : [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)