# how to get details of email account configured with android phone?

Tags: android

I want details from mail account configured in android phone with default application email client or any gmail etc.I need details used when configuring it ,like

1.incoming server or host

2. port

3. email id

4. password

5. outgoing server or host

6. port

7. if there is ssl encryption etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to get all the details which are configured in Email application, but if you want get the Android device's primary e-mail address, you have this two good examples:

[How-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Hope it helps.