# Get identifier of a smartphone

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I´m writing an app where i a user can store a text in a SQL Database. This is send via AJAX to my server and via PHP to the SQL database. There should be a restriction: The user should be able to upload a text only once! I first mentioned the IP, but if you´re online with GPRS (carrier) then multiple devices got the same IP adress.

How can I identify the smartphone, which is accessing the database?

Comment: I guess you aren't using any specific user credentials in your app?

Comment: Might this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: nope no credentials... no login...

Comment: @iaindownie i don´t think, that all of my users have their email adress installed on their phone. :( thx 4 your help!

Comment: OK, see this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id
I don't know if you really NEED IP addresses, or just reasonably unique.

Comment: this is in JAVA. I´m developing in HTMl CSS JS and phonegap...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33135/discussion-between-m1crdy-and-iaindownie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the DeviceID as a unique itendtifier. In Phonegap you can get it with:

```
var id = device.uidd;
```