# In-app purchase: get the name or ID of the Google Play account that's requesting a purchase

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing, android-account

I want to get a name / ID of the user making a purchase. I would like to do without `AccountManager` if possible, as its use requires an extra permission. Even with `AccountManager` I don't see a way to determine the current account, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: Possible help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address Another possible help: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html

Comment: @LuckyMe: those don't show how to actually get a _current_ Google Play account with `AccountManager`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that's even possible. I tried all possible ways before contacting Google support. And the reply I got was this:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support. Please note that Google does not provide access to any confidential user
>   information, such as email address, mailing address, or phone numbers.
>   We place a high value on user confidentiality and privacy, so I'm sure
>   you can understand our position regarding this information.
>
> We sincerely appreciate your understanding. Thanks for supporting
>   Google Play!
>
> Regards, Google Play Developer Support

In the query, we had clarified that it is for post-sales support.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't need any confidential information, though. I just need some ID unique for this account.

Comment: I understood that. But Google is not going to give any unique ID. I have tried my best. Please update your question if you make any progress with that. 

Also, I have gone through my earning reports on Merchant portal. All I can get is a unique orderID.

Answer (score 0):

Google stores an inventory of everything the user purchased via in app billing. You may be able to use an ID from one of the purchases as a unique id for your user. Of course, this requires that users purchase something first.