# Why i'm not being able to get the device's main email?

Tags: android, permissions

I'm developing an application which requires the user main account([like posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)) but i'm having following error:

```
the caller ui 10134 lacks of any of android.permisson.GET_ACCOUNTS
```

I guess that means permisson error(obviously). So i added following lines to my manifest.

```
    <application>
...


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" ></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" ></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    </application>
```

But string not work. What could be the problem? What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put permissions before the `<application></application>` tag and it will work !

**Edit:** and the uses-permission is a single tag like : `<uses-permission />`