# Get email that was used for downloading app

Tags: android

I wish to know what email address was used for accessing google play.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) question, but when I tested out the top answer, I saw multiple email addresses listed, *two* of which had the type "com.google". So how could I have determined which of those two was associated with google play?

**EDIT:** To anyone thinking of marking this as a duplicate... please read the **whole** of my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Comment: i'm not entirely sure you can know how an application was installed. It could have come from anywhere beside the play store.

Comment: @njzk2: Point taken. But I'd still like to knoe what email address is currently associated with google play.

Comment: For that you can ask the user directly using `newChooseAccountIntent` in AccountManager

Comment: some user may install application directly from their computer if they have the phone connected to the computer, in this way you won t have the address.