# Retrieving all google mails in Android application

Tags: android, smtp, gmail, imap

I want to retrieve all google emails in Android application code. Can anyone please mention/tell the APIs which can be used to retrieve the emails and display those mails in browser or in a list view. then after clicking on the item, show the contents of the mail?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see this link. It may help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: @Ankit: The above mentioned link discusses the accounts configured on android device using AccountManager but I am asking about how to retrieve emails after showing a dialog to user for asking username and password.

Comment: Why can't you just send them to gmail.com? That seems to meet all your requirements.

Comment: @Max: I am not using web browser. I am making a client where you can configure different email accounts. You can add GMAIL, Yahoo etc. For that I need to fetch the information from the email provider. Is this making sense?