# Push notification android GCM

Tags: php, android

I'm a beginner with android apps.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and it works, but in permissions is `GET_ACCOUNTS`, and when app is run there is display input for name and email. How I can make change, without input name and email, just taking from `GET_ACCOUNTS`? I don't understand it. Can anybody explain how?

Answer (score 1):

In my last apk, I had the same issue. But I found in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2175688/2157878) answer.

I hope it's useful

In manifest check the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

And in the method:

```
public String getEmail(){
    String possibleEmail= "no email";
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(ctx).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            possibleEmail = account.name;              
        }
    }

    return possibleEmail;

}
```

And in example change to:

```
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
    ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, getEMail(), registrationId);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but how i can integrate with this code? look link in my post? Can you help me with some suggestion?

Comment: hmm, i cant figure it :S can you give me ur skype id? or something, can we chat?

Comment: Tnx, can u give your some contact? i need help with this? skype or something

Comment: i'm getting errors when i put this code :/ please can u help me on chat?

Comment: i cant implement this :S can anybody help me?

Comment: Look, how i can make change with your code? when i have this  http://pokit.org/get/img/fabb01cb180a9f08d55376fa925f0da5.jpg input for name and email, this is mainactivity, can you please look link for tutorial, i use that code, and how to make change? what i need to delete?