# Cordova plugin (for ver > 3) for Android account manager

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, accountmanager

I've been on this for past few days, may be because am not that strong on the JAVA side... I am trying to get the list of an android device's email accounts (or simply - accounts) using Cordova. There is a plugin available for this but it's compatible only for a Cordova app with version less than 2.9.

So, I built a new plugin with the instruction available at phonegap website and hosted this plugin [on the GIT](https://github.com/AccountManagerPlugin). While adding this to my project, I receive errors related to the JS and also, my main JAVA class - accountmanager shows an error at the "Context".

Can anybody help me looking at the plugin I tried to bring together with the help of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) and phoengap's plugin development guide...

Is my plugin a complete one at all? Kindly guide me..

***UPDATE:***
I updated my JAVA and javascript files, and now when I add the plugin, I get a new error -as follows -

```
Uncaught module com.am.accountmanager.accountmanager already defined : line 79 in cordova.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a working/tested plugin](https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin) for retrieving an android device information - This includes every piece of information about an android device...