# Android send mail using JavaMail API using google account details from setting screen

Tags: android

I can send the mail in background without user interaction using JavaMail Api as described in the link
`http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android`.

The above approach requires to hard code the `username` and `password` for smtp server, is it possible to send the mail using google account that the user registered on the `setting` application?

Comment: you can't get password of registered Email, you can get Address in code but you need Both for sending via JavaMail.

Comment: may this link help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: That would be a serious offense to use someone's own email and password without his/her permission to send email to anyone without knowing anybody!...