# Tracking android application users Email address

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Is it possible to track the users email address who had installed my application from google play store using google analytics?

If it is not possible then is there any other way?

Please guide me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Bskania.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Comment: I know how I can get the primary email address but I want to track that email address with analytics with user data.

Comment: Make sure you encrypt there email address somehow its against the rules with analytics to upload the anything that could be directly mapped back to a user by Google. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/user-id

Comment: Even if you encrpyt the email address, it violates the terms of Google Analytics [data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset), even in hashed form](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en)