# How to get the email contacts associated with my email account on device

Tags: android, gmail, google-contacts-api

I am first time on stack-overflow, so please forgive me if I am not able to explain the question properly  OR not following the policies of this community in any way.

**My Question is :** Today morning I was learning from stack-overflow and suddenly a question struck my mind. Supposed my email address is **simran....@gmail.com** and this is currently **logged-In**  in my device. So how to get the all email contacts associated with my email account. I have **200+**  folks added in my gmail account, so want to show these all in listview.

**Note :** I know how to implement the list-view and how to get the [primary email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) address and other email logged-in my device.

**What I Need :** I want to fetch all email contacts of **simran....@gmail.com**. Is this possible and if the answer is yes then how? Can we get this without permission of user?

Thanks
Simran

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Show_Phone_Contacts_In_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=106&aaid=128

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar, thanks for comment. But please read my question carefully.

Comment: @simrantyagi You can use google 
[contacts api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts)

Comment: @M4ver1k, Is there any simple way to do this. have you Used this api.

Comment: @simrantyagi have a look at [this](http://tush.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/android-google-contact-api-3-0-example/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to get all the email contacts from your contact list -

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails(){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                new String[]{id}, null); 
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                    //to get the contact names
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.add(name);
                    }
                } 
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

You have to add permission -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Without this permission its seems not to be possible.

Comment: It does not return any thing to Name & Email.