# Is it possible to view my android app user emails

Tags: android

I have a requirement by a client. Since I am new to mobile app development (I am more into web apps), I was wandering if Google lets you view the emails of an android app than you own.

If not emails, at least google usernames.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "emails of an android app than you own." do you mean emails your app sends? If so why not grab them as you're sending them

Comment: No I mean, which users are actually using my app (identified by their gmail accounts)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Comment: The duplicate link should answer your question. Of course your app will have to have appropriate permissions and you should be up front with your users as to what you're doing