# How to get User's name?

Tags: android

I know, other people asked the same question, but the answers don't work for me.

I tried this 
https://github.com/jehy/Android-GetOwnerInfo/blob/master/Android-get-owner-contact-info.java  in this way:

```
 OwnerInfo i = new OwnerInfo(this);
    System.out.println(i.accountName);
    System.out.println(i.email);
    System.out.println(i.id);
    System.out.println(i.phone);
    System.out.println(i.name);
```

i.accountName gives me the email, but all other deliver null.

and this 
[How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) in this way:

```
MyLoaderManager mLoaderManager = new MyLoaderManager(this);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, (LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this);
```

with the code from the Link in MyLoaderManager.

and played with the Account Manager, but nothing could give me my Name(or I used them in the wrong way?). But other Apps like Vine, Pinterest or Twitter can propose me my Name during the registration process, so there must be a way. So, how do they do this?

Comment: What happened when you tried to use the GitHub project you mentioned?

Comment: **"...nothing could give me my Name(or I used them in the wrong way?)."** : Well as you haven't posted any code, we have no idea if you're using them in the right ot wrong way. Post code and somebody may be able to help.

Comment: @Squonk I edited the Question. But is it generally possible to receive the name this was?