# How to get google drive account name

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, android-googleapiclient

I am using Google Drive core API for file CRUD. All things are working fine but I am unable to get Google Drive account name in onActivityResult() method. My code is as follows:

In `onCreate()`:

```
String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
                        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                                accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_AUTH);
```

In `onAcivityResult()`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int rqst, final int rslt,
                    final Intent data) {
                if ((rqst == REQ_AUTH) && (rslt == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {

                    accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

                    if (accountName != null) {
                        googleApiClient.init(UploadFileOnGoogleDrive.this, accountName)
                                .connect();
                    }
                }
```

Here, `data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME)` always returning `null`. I also putted condition like d`ata!=null && data.getStringExtras()!=null` but the condition never get satisfied. Please help me.

Comment: You mean to say the google account which is synced with google play store in the device

Comment: check it out this link [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2175688/2715073)

Comment: Did you check the permissions in your manifest (GET_ACCOUNTS)?