# Android Get Information of Owner account of Application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Is there anyway to get owner of Application from which any specific application is downloaded.

I have a scenario in which I need to call [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get)

to verify in-app purchases on server side. where I need email address from which in-app purchase was performed.I have read somewhere that purchases will be performed from the account which was used to download application ( owner account of application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Comment: No it's not, because I don't want to get primary account. I need to get application owner account from which any application is downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get email address from which application is downloaded. Because you could get the apk from other sources as well. There is no proper answer for that. You could only use a small heck by just fetching all Gmail address and store the last one, it may not be the required email address, but it should be the first added Google account. Usually, people add their original email address - (I am not referencing developer here)