# Cannot find local variable 'ac'

Tags: java, android, android-debug

Below my code but it is not working - refer to [this screenshot of the error during debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYTXT.png),

> Cannot find local variable 'ac'

```
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
    for (final Account ac : accounts)
    {
        String acname = ac.name;
        System.out.println("Accounts : " + acname);

    }
```

Comment: check this--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: working properly.

Comment: So what?What is the problem with my code?

Comment: I agree with @DheerubhaiBansal that code should compile ok. Can you show the exact error message, i.e. what line and/or position in that line? For now, my comment is: *Unable to reproduce*.

Comment: You get this error during normal execution? or only in the debug? Please show the logcat

Answer (score 3):

From your screenshot I saw that you are using `Android Studio` and there is no problem with your code, but rather some debug settings. If you'll open `Android Studio` preferences and go to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data Views` you'll probably see the option `Enable auto expressions in Variables view` ticked, since it is ticked by default. It should look something like this: [image: Android Studio Preferences] 
Now, if you'll check the `IntelliJ` [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/data-views.html) for that you'll find this (note that `IntelliJ` and `Android Studio` are running on the same engine in case that you are wondering why I said about `IntelliJ` docs):

> Select this option if you want the IntelliJ IDEA debugger to automatically evaluate expressions and show the corresponding values in the Variables pane of the Debug tool window.
>
> The debugger analyzes the context near the breakpoint (the current statement, one statement before, and one after). It does so to find various expressions in the source code (if available) such as, for example, myvar.myfield.
>
> If such expressions don't contain explicit method invocations, the debugger evaluates them and shows the corresponding values in the Variables view.

Basically, they are saying that the IDE will check the code around a breakpoint to identify the variables and compute their values (method calls not included). That being said, when the control reaches the line where `accounts variable` is declared, the IDE will check the code for variables and will found the `ac` variable, but will fail to compute its values since at the execution point that variable isn't declared yet, hence the entire operation will end with the message that the variable cannot be found.
To fix this, you have to uncheck that option from settings or you can leave it just like this, since it will not affect your code (it is fully functional right now).