# Getting user's name in Android

Tags: android, google-signin, user-data, android-account

I would like to get the user's name in my app so that it can provide a personalized message during it's first run like,

> Hey *%user's name*,
>
> ..

Since the app will be paid and primarily available on Google Play Store, i would have all the information about the user as in their synced gmail account. But how do i go about writing code for it?

Comment: You compile the Google Sign-In API, probably

Comment: Or, if you just want to read the primary contact, you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address#2175688

Comment: The device may not know the user's name. Not all devices ask for a name as part of the setup wizard, and I have yet to encounter one that forces the user to provide a name. Also, not all users will associate any sort of account (e.g., Google account) with their device.

Comment: @cricket_007 isn't Google Sign-In API for websites? and i need their name..

Comment: @CommonsWare not the device itself, no, but google does when you create an account. And since the app will be a paid one available primarily on Google Play Store, they need a gmail account to pay for it.

Comment: Nope, works on Android. https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by cricket_007, Google Sign-In API provides the [user's display name](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people).

[image]