# If - Email Account with "@xyz.com" extension exist do something [Xamarin]

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm very new to Xamarin and android development, I have developed simple widget which used in my company but I need to limit the app:

If there is email account on android device which have "@xyz.com" extension the app will work.

If there is no email with "@xyz.com" extension the app will display error message.

**My question is how its possible to search all accounts in android device and detect the "@xyz.com" extension.
If someone have example or piece of code it will be very helpful.**

The closest example that I've found is:

http://androidexample.com/Get_Registered_Email_Accounts_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=110

But I didn't managed to convert it to Xamarin.

Thanks a lot,

David

Comment: What is the error? Why didn't you manage to covert it to C#? What did you try yourself? Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how a question should be formulated for your increasing your chances of getting an answer you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite difficult to convert java to c#, most APIs are encapsulate in Xamarin with the same name.

There are several methods to solve your problem. For example you can use `AccountManager`. To use `AccountManager`, you need open your AndroidManifest.xml under `properties` of your project and add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Then for example code like this:

```
var emialPattern = Patterns.EmailAddress;
var accounts = AccountManager.Get(this).GetAccounts();
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    if (emialPattern.Matcher(account.Name).Matches())
    {
        string email = account.Name;
        string[] emailarray = email.Split('@');
        if (emailarray[1] == "xyz.com")
        {
            //TODO:
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO:
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest to read the answer of this case: [How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address). Next time if you meet some problem while trying to convert Java code to c#, please show us what you've tried and post your code.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is very helpful !