# Get Android device's primary email address in React Native Android App

Tags: android, react-native

Is there any good react native library to get primary email address of android devices.
There is a Stackoverflow question to get it with native android ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)). I need include it in react native android app.

Update: I could get email address from following method with android native. Now I need to implement it in react native.

permission:

**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"**

method:

```
  String emailAddress = "";
    private String getEmail() {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(
                    "com.google");
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                if (i > 0)
                    sGoogleId = account.name;
                else
                    sGoogleId = account.name;
                i++;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return emailAddress;
    }
```

Comment: That question's accepted answer is incorrect, insofar as it is not guaranteed to get you any valid email address.

Comment: @CommonsWare Atleast I need to get a list of all account names on the device. In our case we can have a rule to restrict it to a single account. Is it possible?

Comment: I do not know whether React Native has any support for this. My point is that you cannot get a useful user's email address this way. If you want to get the email address that the user wants to use, ask them for their email address.

Comment: @CommonsWare we can't do that. We need to restrict users based on email domain address.

Comment: That is impractical. There are many email apps and users that do not use the Android account system. You have no means of accessing those email addresses programmatically. Conversely, there are lots of people who might have a Google account registered, but they never use any associated Gmail account. Or, the Gmail account is not one that the user wants you to use (e.g., it is a work account).

Comment: @CommonsWare: I could retrieve that email id as in updated code. Now only need to convert it to react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by using react native Native module. Device should have at-least one google account. Since it takes some time to process the request need to collect with a promise `(androidManager.getAccounts().then(){}.Done(){})`.

Comment: I fail to see how this is the answer?

Comment: @Norfeldt Is there any wrong with above answer? It sorted my problem. What is the problem you have?

Comment: Trying `import { androidManager } from 'react-native'` is not possible. I can't find any docs on androidManager on the offical react native site

Comment: @Norfeldt You can't use it like that. Above code is native android code. But you can use native codes in a react native apps (react native Native module).

Comment: Check following link. You can use that library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-account-manager

Comment: Thx but I already tried that - https://github.com/GoIntegro/react-native-account-manager/issues/4

Comment: @Norfeldt I have created above additional method in native code(RN Native module) and use following code in react native. It works fine.    
 <!-- language: lang-js -->
   
    var am = NativeModules.RNAccountManagerModule;
    am.getAccounts()
    .catch((err) => { //alert('Can not read user account primary email address'); }).done((response) => {if(!response) {
  alert("Check whether all permissions are granted");
 }else {this.setState({ sitemail: response });
    //alert(this.state.sitemail)
    }
});
});

Comment: `var am = NativeModules.RNAccountManagerModule;
    am.getAccounts()
    .catch((err) => { //alert('Can not read user account primary email address'); }).done((response) => {if(!response) {
  alert("Check whether all permissions are granted");
 }else {this.setState({ sitemail: response });
    //alert(this.state.sitemail)
    }
});
});`

Comment: I might be stupid at this, but I don't know how to implement it. I do know the concept about NativeModules (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html). What (and where) JAVA code do I need to drop into the android folder?

Comment: Check the following links 1: [how to](https://shift.infinite.red/native-modules-for-react-native-android-ac05dbda800d) 2. [intro](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)

Comment: @LittleOne you should share the entire code here.