# Where to find my Play store App user's Email ID or Phone Number

Tags: android, google-play

I want to know where I can find the Email Id or Phone Number of User's who have or had downloaded my App from Play store.
I have searched in Play store Console but it only shows Data Like IP address or region or the country from where the App was downloaded or the number of downloads.
The problem is I am uploading a new version of my App and need to get in contact with those who have downloaded my App earlier so that they can now use the new App.
To reach out to them I will need their Email address or contact no.

Please help!!!!
Thank you in Advance for the same.

Comment: Google -play is not providing any email/phone number of the user who have/had your app. If you upload a new version of the App to play store than it will automatically notified the user about the update of your app and other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the UserID's / phone numbers of people who download your app.

Comment: Is there any alternative??..To get these details

Comment: Ask for them. Many apps open with a screen that asks users to enter their phone number, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I don'tt think Google will give this data. But you can do it yourself.

Get Phone Number

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

[How to get the Android device's primary e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

There is another solution "google firebase notification". https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/

but I guess there is nothing to do for the old user.