# What permissions do I need to get user's email?

Tags: android, permissions

I am testing the following code to get the email registered in the device-

```
  String gmail = null;
    Pattern gmailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (gmailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            gmail = account.name;
        }
    }
```

This code does not work on `Android O` until I add the `READ_CONTACTS` permission.

But It needs the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission to work on API 16. and once I add that, for some reason it stops working on android O.

What permissions do I need from what API level to what? My `minSdkVersion` is 16

Comment: go through : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: I want to minimise the use of permissions and use only the necessary ones

Comment: @Sahil I did already, and that answer is not accurate as he does not mention the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission which is necessary on android O