# How to get Email Adress of a device user?

Tags: java, android

Can you Help me with this Code? It should get emailadresses from the current Android Device but it Returns null every time.
I have tried it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address) but still getting null every time

```
 public String getUsername() {
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            String possibleEmail = account.name;
            return possibleEmail;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here my Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Upload FTP"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Where did you find that code to get the user email from an Android device? Are you following some guide?

Comment: i Found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: Can you share your Manifest file

Comment: Sure sorry for that bad explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code works great for me. All you have to do is

In your OnCreate() have the below code and tweak as per your requirement

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 1);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 1);
        }
    }
        else {
        List<String> accountList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern gmailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (gmailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                accountsList.add(account.name);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), account.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

and then you have to add Permission of GET_ACCOUNTS in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Maybe I am stupid but i get an error on Item i = new Item. If i try to Import it I get ClipData.Item and i guess thats not correct. :(

Comment: @user12346352 : Actually Item is a repo/pojo class. Nothing to worry about that, I have made changes to code. You can verify. Vote up if it works.

Comment: Nice, now it works thx for that :)

Comment: Lines 3 and 5 absolutelly identical. Why this if-else construction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for the user's email address to be visible to other apps by any means. There certainly is no requirement that the user have an account in `AccountManager` whose account name is an email address *and is an email address that the user actively uses*. For example, just because the user set up a Google account on the device does not mean that the user uses the Gmail associated with that account.

If you want the user's email address, **ask them what they want to use**.

Comment: If i understand that Right a Windows should Pop up where he can enter the emailadress? Can you give me a Code example how I can do that?