# How to pull phone's primary email id from flutter for auto-filling a registration form?

Tags: gmail, flutter, gmail-api

**Without Making User Sign-in with Google** as the below link suggests

How to access logged in **email** id from google accounts of a phone using flutter.

[Here it shows how to access primary mail id from android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address)

Answer (score 2):

You got to let him log in with his account first.

1 - make your user sign in using the Google Sign in package
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in

2 - you can sign the returned user to your backend or a firebase backend simply with this (won't explain the whole process here)

3 - you can access all google api (some access scope can be required, scopes have to be provided on step 1)
here is the flutter google api to access all google method 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis

Comment: Is there any alternative without making user login with google account?

Comment: you can't make things on user account without asking him to do so... that's the rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in flutter via custom [platform-channels](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) .Please be careful and up-front to the user when dealing with account, profile, and contact data.

This requires both the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

you can use [simple_permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions) plugin to request/check the access

Open the file MainActivity.java located in the android java folder in the Project.

add the following code to get the emails from the device in the oncreate method

```
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                        if (call.method.equals("getEmailList")) {
                            final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
                            Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
                            List<String> possibleEmails = new ArrayList<String>();

                            for (Account account : accounts) {
                                possibleEmails.add(account.name);
                                System.out.print(account.name);
                            }
                            /*Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
                            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccounts();
                            for (Account account : accounts) {
                                if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                                    primaryEmail = account.name;
                                }
                            }*/
                            result.success(possibleEmails);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

and you can call the method from your flutter code via the methodchannel

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/email');
var emailist   = await platform.invokeMethod('getEmailList');
```

full sample [project](https://github.com/shyjuzz/flutter-samples/tree/master/emailpicker)